# Multiple availability groups--can each availability group have its own listener?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups

I have created two availability groups containing multiple databases on the same SQL Server instance.  Can I have two different listeners for these two availability groups?

Comment: Yes you can have multiple Listeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can and should create one listener per Availability Group.  This is mentioned in passing in the MS Docs article [Configure a listener for an Always On availability group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/create-or-configure-an-availability-group-listener-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017):

> You can create only one listener per availability group through SQL Server. Typically, each availability group requires only one listener.